# How to name a subprocess in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

In Python 2.7, I have a producer which kicks off several subprocesses:

```python
processes.append(subprocess.Popen(command, env=my_env)
```

I also have a consumer which checks the status of the subprocesses and then do some work:

```python
for proc in processes:
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        # do some work
```

I need to assign each subprocess a name when kicking them off so that the consumer can print out something like:"`Subprocess xxx finished!`"

How can I do that?

Comment: Append a tuple of `('Name', proc)`, then unpack it again when you iterate `processes`?

Comment: Or use a `dict`? `processes[name] = subprocess.Popen(...)`

Comment: Take a look at multiprocessing.Pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't make clear what `processes` is; you say “a producer which kicks off several subprocesses”, but that doesn't tell us what the type is and what it's capable of.

So, when you use `processes.append`, I'll assume `processes` is just a sequence with `list`-like semantics.

Why do they need a name? Processes already get assigned a process ID by the operating system. You can do this:

```python
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, env=my_env)
processes.append(proc)

for proc in processes:
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        # do some work
    else:
        print("Subprocess {proc.pid} finished!".format(proc=proc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the PID of the process as the name, that way you don't need to invent an arbitrary naming scheme:

```
for proc in processes:
    # Do whatever
    print "Subprocess {} finished!".format(proc.pid)
```